# How to modify the tag <tbody> using StringBuilder (ASP.NET C#)?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to insert a table using StringBuilder, but I need to edit some **"tbody"** tags, but it just ignores anything that I try:

I tried without success:

`sb.AppendLine("<table><tbody class=' any-class'>");`

It just create a **tbody** without any class in the HTML page.

Tried to insert another tag other than tr, th, td:

`sb.AppendLine("<table><div class=' any-class'>");`

In this case it create an empty table with the tag before the main table, in other words, it create a table just for the tag, and then creates a table with the content that I want.

The only way to change the **tbody** properties was putting it in the CSS directly:

```
`tbody {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column wrap;
            max-height: 1360px;
        }`
```

But I don't want to apply this changes to all tables, there's anything that I'm doing wrong or that I can do to fix it?

Comment: There must be a step between you creating the string and the browser rendering it. How did you look at the rendered output? Have you tried writing the content of the stringbuilder to a file to check it is what you intend it to be?

Comment: Can you post the full method where you're using the `StringBuilder`? There's another factor involved that's causing your issue. The code posted won't give the behavior you're describing. It could be something as simple as a missed character in the markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend setting the class on the table itself. Then you can set the classes of the elements. Note the use of `\"` to get a double quote in a string.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.AppendLine("<table class=\"any-class\">");
sb.AppendLine("<thead>");
sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
sb.AppendLine("<th>Name</th>");
sb.AppendLine("<th>Age</th>");
sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
sb.AppendLine("</thead>");
sb.AppendLine("<tfoot>");
sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
sb.AppendLine("<td>Total</td>");
sb.AppendLine("<td>2</td>");
sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
sb.AppendLine("</tfoot>");
sb.AppendLine("<tbody>");
sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
sb.AppendLine("<td>Jane</td>");
sb.AppendLine("<td>45</td>");
sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
sb.AppendLine("<tr>");
sb.AppendLine("<td>John</td>");
sb.AppendLine("<td>20</td>");
sb.AppendLine("</tr>");
sb.AppendLine("</tbody>");
sb.AppendLine("</table>");

Literal1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Now that the `table` has the `any-class` class, you can set the CSS.

```
<style>
    .any-class {
        border: 2px dotted red;
    }

        .any-class td {
            padding: 3px;
            color: blue;
        }

        .any-class tbody {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: column wrap;
            max-height: 1360px;
        }

        .any-class tfoot {
            background-color: #c5c5c5;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
</style>
```

But building tables like this is not very efficient. Note that a `GridView` is also a `table` in HTML. Or you can create a 'real' table in code behind with `Table table = new Table();`